# Combine Current Directory with file name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have tested the following two codes .The first one works as I'm giving the full path name but the second one give the error saying the file is not found.The value of the path location is shown same in both the cases.I think i'm not concatenating the stings right.I have also tried to give the filename without the extension.Any help?

1st code

```
    Dim content As String
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\****\bin\Debug\tns.txt"
    MessageBox.Show(path)
    Try
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(path)
        content = sr.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(content)
        MessageBox.Show(content)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
```

2nd code

```
 Dim content As String
    Dim path As String
    path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\tns.txt"
    MessageBox.Show(path)
    Try
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(path)
        content = sr.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(content)
        MessageBox.Show(content)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
```

Comment: Just use Path.Combine.

Comment: [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) exists. It exists so you don't have to worry about concatenating strings (and whether, for instance, separator characters are potentially duplicated)

Comment: What is the contents of "path" for each code block?Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() returns the path to the current working directory of the application

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path = IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "tns.txt")
```

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: It goes to the correct location but says file not found.

Comment: Then you must be getting different paths outputed by the different pieces of code. Try running both into seperate variables and doing a compare to check they are the same.

Comment: But i checked multiple times that currentdir+tns.txt is same as the absolute location of the file

Answer (score 0):

Works with single slash `"\tnx.txt"`

Comment: Replace single slash "\tnx.txt" with double slash "\\tns.txt"

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid - but this is a VB question and VB doesn't use backslash based escapes in strings.

Comment: It works with single slash, I've checked your code in VB. You should check location of your document, I don't think that would be in the location of your project/debug/bin/tns.txt