# Unable to open txt file path

Tags: vb.net, file, path

This code runs perfectly when I hard code the path to the textfile. But as suggested, it is much better not to hard code stuff. I tried it this way and still can't find the txt file even if it exists.

```
Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + " Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt")
Dim Lookfor As String = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

'MessageBox.Show(Findstring.ToString())
showdat.Text = Lookfor

If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
    'MsgBox("Found: " & Lookfor)
    For Each prog As Process In Process.GetProcesses
         If prog.ProcessName = "Redmi03-JCO0531-WX" Then
             prog.Kill()
             Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "Redmi03-JCO0531-WX.exe")
         End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Did you actually look at the value of `Findstring`?  I can pretty much guarantee that you didn't because there's no way that it contains the path you want.

Comment: Yep, I doubled check the date and it was existing I also tried hard coding it and it founds. The errors says something like " C:\user\desktop\foldername\ `debug` Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_20191115 was not found. Im not sure why it is pushing though the debug folder. So I tried putting the txt file on the debug folder but it says the same

Comment: Heres a screenshot @jmcilhinney https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxDzd.png
But the folder is actually at C:\Users\support.jbp\Desktop\ChinaUMS Bank\Redmi03\Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_20191115

Comment: The string concatenation character in vb.net is the & (ampersand). It will accept the + character but you can get unexpected results when numbers are involved. There is a backslash expected between a directory name and the filename. Check out `Path.Combine` and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Mary I am actually reading it now 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890087/combine-current-directory-with-file-name-in-vb-net
can you guide me what to change

Comment: I just realised that `Findstring` is not the file path but the file contents.  Your first mistake was not bothering to actually look at the data you're using.  Your second mistake was not reading the relevant documentation.  The documentation for `GetCurrentDirectory` explicitly states that the path returned does not include a trailing slash and the file name that you're specifying has a leading space.  There's no way that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + " Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt"` can reasonably produce the path you want.

Comment: so what is the best way to produce the path @jmcilhinney

Comment: As suggested, you should use `Path.Combine` to combine partial paths.  I can handle cases with either, neither or both leading and trailing slashes.  As always, you should start by reading the relevant documentation and then, if needed, check out existing examples on the web.  You should also avoid putting erroneous spaces in your `String` literals.  I guess I don;t know for a fact that your file name doesn't start with a space but it seems a fairly silly thing to do.  Even if you didn't use `Path.Combine`, simple debugging would show what's wrong with that path and you could fix it.

Comment: Never use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, you don't know what Directory is the *current*. When you start your app from the IDE, it is the path to your executable. After that, it can be anything else. Use `Application.StartupPath` (e.g., WinForms), `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` (e.g., WPF) etc. Always use `Path.Combine()` to generate a valid path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is at this line

```
Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + " Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt")
```

Let's break that down and see what each part really is.

First at the top of the code file add

```
Imports System.IO
```

Then in your Form class

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dir As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    MessageBox.Show(dir)
    Dim TextFileName = " Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
    MessageBox.Show(TextFileName)
    Dim CompletePath = Path.Combine(dir, TextFileName)
    MessageBox.Show(CompletePath)
    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(CompletePath)
End Sub
```

Actually, you can add a break point and step through the code checking the values of your in your code instead of all these silly Message Boxes. If the 3rd MessageBox does not show the actual location of your file then it is back to the drawing board.

**EDIT**

Edit to get path on desktop.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    MessageBox.Show(dir)
    Dim TextFileName = "ChinaUMS Bank\Redmi05\Redmi03-JCO0531-WX_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
    MessageBox.Show(TextFileName)
    Dim CompletePath = Path.Combine(dir, TextFileName)
    MessageBox.Show(CompletePath)
    ' Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(CompletePath)
End Sub
```

Notice that you must hardcode the sub-folders. The special folder will get the Desktop path for the current user.

Comment: Ill give it a try.

Comment: @JohnBuan As suggested in the comments, use `Application.StartupPath` instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. And have you tried checking `File.Exists()` ?

Comment: @preciousbetine I will try again your advice

Comment: @JohnBuan What is the exact path to the text file?

Comment: @JohnBuan To get the exact path go to File Explorer. Locate your text file and highlight it. In the ribbon click Copy Path. You can now paste this into a comment. You do realize that you have the same problem in your ProcessStart code. You are missing the backslash.

Comment: @Mary this is the exact file path of the txt file C:\Users\support.jbp\Desktop\ChinaUMS Bank\Redmi05

actually it works now but still I hard code the `path` part

Comment: @JohnBuan Please see the EDIT to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for all of your efforts! @Mary

Comment: @JohnBuan `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and `Application.StartupPath` points to your current project's debug folder. For the first method in this answer to work, place the text file in your debug folder.